# How to compare two hash values in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

Here is my code.

```
   pragma solidity >=0.8.0;
    contract marketplace{
      bytes32 offerFromConsumer;
      bytes32 offerFromProducer;

      function setValuea(bytes32 a) external{
          offerFromProducer = a;
      }

      function setValueb(bytes32 b) external{
          offerFromConsumer = b;
      } 

      function checkOffers() public view returns (bool){

          bytes32 a = offerFromProducer;
          bytes32 b = offerFromConsumer;

          if(a == b){
              return true;
          }
          return false;
    }    
}
```

if else is not working for bytes32?

Comment: It is working for me.  Some improvements 1. use one solidity version and maybe ` pragma solidity 0.8.12;` and not ">=". 2. you can do ``` return offerFromProducer == offerFromConsumer```

Comment: I want to compare salted + hash value using bytes32.It doesnt work?

Comment: Give an example with expected result and actual result

Comment: I want to compare "72AE25495A7981C40622D49F9A52E4F1565C90F048F59027BD9C8C8900D5C3D8" and "B4B6603ABC670967E99C7E7F1389E40CD16E78AD38EB1468EC2AA1E62B8BED3A". when I give this two values it give true.But I need false.

Answer (score 0):

It gives me false as expected

```
pragma solidity 0.8.12;

contract marketplace {

    bytes32 public offerFromConsumer;
    bytes32 public offerFromProducer;

    function setValuea(bytes32 a) external{
      offerFromProducer = a;
    }

    function setValueb(bytes32 b) external{
      offerFromConsumer = b;
    } 

    function checkOffers() public view returns (bool) {
      return offerFromProducer == offerFromConsumer;
    }    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have not inserted 0x infront.:)